# Paypal Website Payment Standard integration

Tags: paypal

What are the private key, Your Public Certificate etc etc of Paypal payment standard. I cant get these things creating sandbox test accounts?
So sucking thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use it in the first place. It's great when it works, but any whitespace / crappy WYSIWYG editor will kill your button.
I'd strongly suggest looking at hosted buttons and/or Express Checkout through API instead.

To answer your question, though; have a look at http://www.spicelogic.com/Products/PayPal-Certificate-Generator-for-Encrypted-Website-Payments-9 which has a handy little tool along with some usage tips.